# Does self-product of universal hypersurfaces have dlt singularites?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $n\geq2,d\geq 2n+1$ be integers, let $\mathcal{X}_{n,d}\to|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)|$ be the universal family of hypersurfaces. The total space $\mathcal{X}_{n,d}$ is smooth as it is a projective bundle over $\mathbb{P}^n$.

The self-product $T:=\mathcal{X}_{n,d}\times_{|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)|}\mathcal{X}_{n,d}$ is a complete intersection in $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)|_{}\times \mathbb{P}^n_{[X_0,\cdots,X_n]}\times\mathbb{P}^n_{[Y_0,\cdots,Y_n]}$, defined by $\sum a_IX^I=0,\sum a_IY^I=0$. It has singularities in codim at least $4$, therefore it is $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial.

Do we know if $T$ have divisorial log terminal singularities? (for complete intersections, dlt equivalent to canonical singularities, rational singularities) If not, can we say anything about them?

Comment: The blowing up along the diagonal is smooth: it is a projective space bundle over the blowing up of the diagonal in $\mathbb{P}^n\times\mathbb{P}^n$.  Use that resolution to compute the discrepancies.